# Are structs holding the same values considered equal?

Tags: c#, data-structures

Consider this struct.

```
public struct myStruct{
    public int value1;
    public int value2;
    public int value3;

    public myStruct(int val1, int val2, int val3){
        value1 = val1;
        value2 = val2;
        value3 = val3;
    }
}
```

Now consider that I have some list of type `myStruct`:

```
public List<myStruct> myList = new List<myStruct>();
```

Now I instantiate 2 different versions of `myStruct` using the same values:

```
myStruct s1 = new myStruct(1,2,3);
myStruct s2 = new myStruct(1,2,3);
```

I then add the first instance to `myList`:

```
myList.Add(s1);
```

Then I do a simple check to see if the second instance is in the list:

```
bool structsEqual = myList.Contains(s2);
```

Is `structsEqual` true or false?

Comment: Why don't you compile that code and find out? But then again I do love a good quiz! But then again, this isn't a good quiz... :-( (given default behaviour, this will be `true`, by the way).

Comment: and what was output?????

Comment: Instead of typing this code into your browser, why did you not just type it in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interestingly this specific code will equal true but if the struct contained objects there were not system types, then you would have to implement IComparable for this to not always return false.

```
public struct myStruct
{ 
    public MyOwnType value1; 
    public int value2; 
    public int value3; 

    public myStruct(MyOwnType val1, int val2, int val3){ 
        value1 = val1; 
        value2 = val2; 
        value3 = val3; 
    } 
}

public class MyOwnType
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public MyOwnType(int id)
    {
        this.Id = id;
    }
}
```

For Contains to work you would need to implement IComparable:

```
public class MyOwnType : IComparable
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public MyOwnType(int id)
    {
        this.Id = id;
    }

    public int CompareTo(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null) return 1;

        MyOwnType other = obj as MyOwnType;
        if (other != null)
            return this.Id.CompareTo(other.Id);
        else
            throw new ArgumentException("Object is not a MyOwnType");
    }
}
```

Comment: Implement IComparable or override Equals?

Comment: You are right, in this instance Equals would be better as it's contains. IComparable is for ordering. I stand corrected.

Answer (score 1):

You have all the code there, you could put it in a program and run it and see what happens.  I use LinqPad and here is what I get...

```
public List<myStruct> myList = new List<myStruct>(); 

void Main()
{
    myStruct s1 = new myStruct(1,2,3); 
    myStruct s2 = new myStruct(1,2,3); 

    myList.Add(s1); 

    bool structsEqual = myList.Contains(s2); 

    structsEqual.Dump();
}

public struct myStruct{ 
    public int value1; 
    public int value2; 
    public int value3; 

    public myStruct(int val1, int val2, int val3){ 
        value1 = val1; 
        value2 = val2; 
        value3 = val3; 
    } 
}
```

Results = "True"

Answer (score 1):

[Structs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/saxz13w4.aspx) are [value types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch.aspx), so the answer is `True`.

Answer (score 0):

A quick google resulted in the following link:

http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/CSharp/0120__struct/Valuetypeequalitydefaultbehavior.htm

So yes, it will be True